# Will this LINQ-TO-SQL query fetch all records from the table?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net

```
public long GetNewCRN()
{
   return ((from c in DataContext.GetTable<Cust_Master>() 
            select c.CUSTSERH_CRN).Max() + 1);
}
```

Will this `Linq to Sql` query fetch all records from the table first and then select the maximum of the column ?

If yes, then isn't it a bad idea using `linq to sql` instead of normal `SqlCommand` ?

Or is there any other way of doing it in `linq to sql` ?

---

When I attach Console.Out, I see nothing(command prompt does not even open).

But when I include following:-

`context.Log = new System.IO.StreamWriter("d:\\abcd.txt");`

I get an error, that "The process can not access the file because it is being used by another process" and that process is "w3wp.exe".

How can I see the sql commands being executed by DataContext then ?

Comment: Have you tried testing it, and profiling it?

Comment: Getting a new "CRN" like this is a bad idea to begin with... it's **never** going to be safe if multiple users are using this database! If you want an auto-incrementing number (which I think this is what you're doing here), use an `INT IDENTITY` in your table - that's the easiest way to have unique and ever-increasing numbers assigned.

Comment: database is already designed and i have to use it, it's not in my hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this shouldn't fetch all rows. You are only requesting the maximum value. This should be converted to an SQL query like the following:

```
SELECT MAX(CUSTSERH_CRN) FROM Cust_Master
```

You can verify that this is the case by attaching a logger to the DataContext before you execute the command, for example:

```
DataContext.Log = Console.Out;
```

Comment: When I attach Console.Out, I see nothing(command prompt does not even open). Please see my next answer.

Comment: @Puneet Dudeja: You can also use a StringWriter and view the contents of it in the debugger.